# Return javascript data to html/php from prompt

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

My code makes a call to a service called OneID.  The code is javascript and it prompts you to authorize the sharing of your email address (stored in the OneID repository) with a site.

[image: OneID Prompt]

I need the email address to be returned to the parent page if the user clicks, "OK".

Right now, all I can get it to do is generate a javascript Alert.

**Note** If you decide to help with this, you'll need to create a OneID account, sorry.

```
    <script src="https://api.oneid.com/form/form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">

    OneIdExtern.registerApiReadyFunction(
        function(){
            OneId.getUserAttributes(
                {
                    attr: "email[email]", 
                    authLevel : null, 
                    selectCards : true,
                    forceSelectCards : true
                },
                function(data){ 
                    if (data.attribute_data.email.email) {
                        <<-- somehow send data back to page? -->>
                    }
                }   
            );
        }
    );
    </script>';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-code-in-my-javascript-not-work)

Comment: don't use a prompt, use a modal with an `<input type=text>` for the address, and a `<button>` with an onclick handler that then calls the OneID API like you're doing now. Also, why are you echoing this? Just use `?>` instead of the echo, and go back to php with `<?php` afterwards.

Comment: Assuming the email address is in the data returned by OneID, you can call your own function with that data and/or make an ajax-call to a specific document on your server and send the email address as data with that request. It depends on what exactly you want to do with that email address.

Comment: @Sumurai8 -- yes, I actually need to take the email address and curl it to a site within a php environment.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is to inform your backend of the email that have just been entered.
I see 2 way to do this:

1. If user have a form to validate as a next step, just prepare a Hidden field and store the email in there. It will be posted when the form will be validated
2. In real time, you can write a script on your server and call it with the email using **Jquery** (at the place you put you comment:  <<-- somehow send data back to page? -->>). If you need to matchwith  server information, put you'll probably need to maintain a session.

On more remark: if not constraints by cross domain issue, you can make your call directy in javascript instead of curling from your backend.